# Trying to Install Node Globally

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install node globally because every time I create a new directory to use node "node_modules" does not show up and when I run npm run watch it gives me this output

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/*******/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/aroe/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/******/.npm/_logs/2020-01-08T23_12_01_007Z-debug.log
```

I can use node but only in the specific directory I used to install the CDK for TypeScript use. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`node_modules` does not come from node.js itself.  That comes from individual modules you install into that specific project.  The modules built into nodejs are already available automatically as long as you have node itself in your path so you can run it from anywhere.

If you want individual modules to be installed globally, then you install them globally with the -g flag for NPM.  For example:

```
npm -g install express
```

Will install the `express` module globally.

Comment: Thank you! Now do you have any idea why NPM Run Watch will not work?

Comment: @aroe - We would have to see the package.json to have any idea.  `npm run watch` attempts to run an item from the `scripts` object in the package.json file.  Doc [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/run-script.html).

Comment: Do I need to have package.json in every directory I try to work in?

Comment: @aroe - Perhaps you don't understand what the `npm run` command does.  It's entire purpose is to look in the local `package.json` file, find the `scripts` object, find the named property (what you typed after `npm run`, read it's value and execute that script.  The entire command makes no sense if you don't have a package.json file. You do not need a package.json file to run some other npm commands, though package.json in that local directory is where npm keeps a LOT of its data.  So, my question to you is "why are you running `npm run watch` in the first place?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: ok that adds a lot of context. I need to run npm run watch to catch things as I log them when creating this node script. My error shown above is showing that I don't have a package.json anywhere then?

Comment: @aroe - It's showing you that you don' t have `'/Users/aroe/package.json'` and it needs to find the `scripts` object in that file with a `watch` property on it that tells it what script is associated with the `watch` command.  I don't know where you got that instruction from to run that, but wherever that is, it should have come with some sort of setup or instructions for creating or installing the right package.json file.

Comment: do you have any resources to download node properly? Every time I make a directory "node_modules" isn't in it and it gives me the same error.

Comment: @aroe - The `node_modules` directory is NOT part of a node.js installation.  That is created by NPM when you install some third party module in a particular project and NPM puts the installed module code inside the `node_modules` sub-directory.  The modules that come with nodejs such as the `fs` module are built-in (not in separate sub-directories).

Comment: ok, that makes sense thank you. And to clarify, when you install a module in a directory. That "node_modules" folder is created and is specific to that directory only? Also when I try to import it now gives me this error

Comment: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: @aroe - We are so far removed from your original question.  This is not how you should be using StackOverflow.  The `import` statement can only be used in the new ECMAScript modules.  You will have to read https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html to understand how to configure that and it is only support in very new versions of nodejs.  For regular .js modules that nodejs has supported since day one, use `require()` instead of `import`.  I think I've more than answered your original question here.  If you have other questions, please write a new question rather than just adding more here.